# Creating a custom allocator for CHeapPtr (for use with Sqlite)

Tags: c++, winapi, smart-pointers, atl, allocator

I wanted to create some smart pointers for `sqlite3` using `CHeapPtr`.  `CHeapPtr` uses the `CCRTAllocator` class by default, so I figured I'd just create some custom allocator classes that inherit from `CCRTAllocator` but override its `Free` method, so that they use the proper clean-up functions:

```
class CSqlite3Allocator : public CCRTAllocator
{
public:
    static void Free(_In_ sqlite3* p) throw()
    {
        sqlite3_close_v2(p);
    }
};

class CSqlite3StmtAllocator : public CCRTAllocator
{
public:
    static void Free(_In_ sqlite3_stmt* p) throw()
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(p);
    }
};
```

Now I can create `CHeapPtr`s like so:

```
CHeapPtr<sqlite3, CSqlite3Allocator> psqlite;
CHeapPtr<sqlite3_stmt, CSqlite3StmtAllocator> pstmt;
```

These pointers seem to work correctly, and it appears that their clean-up methods are being called.  I was just wondering if this is the proper way of doing this, or if there's a more accepted way of creating custom `CHeapPtr`s.  Thank you for any input.

Comment: Sounds like a good question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to inherit from `CCRTAllocator`, allocator is expected to be just a new class. You can use ATL's [COM heap allocator](https://github.com/knight666/pitstop/blob/6b4323793ee3dce8e16a2a94bf7ed9302e226fc3/Dependencies/WinDDK_7600.16385.1/inc/atl71/atlalloc.h#L719) as an example:

```
class CComAllocator 
{
public:
    static void* Reallocate(void* p, size_t nBytes) throw()
    {
        return ::CoTaskMemRealloc(p, ULONG(nBytes));
    }
    static void* Allocate(size_t nBytes) throw()
    {
        return ::CoTaskMemAlloc(ULONG(nBytes));
    }
    static void Free(void* p) throw()
    {
        ::CoTaskMemFree(p);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class CComHeapPtr :
    public CHeapPtr<T, CComAllocator>
{
public:
    CComHeapPtr() throw()
    {
    }

    explicit CComHeapPtr(T* pData) throw() :
        CHeapPtr<T, CComAllocator>(pData)
    {
    }
};
```

(the code here is shortened a bit for brevity)

The way you implemented can work out but you inherit allocation/reallocation methods from CRT and it makes it a dangerous mix: unintentionally you can end up with CRT `Allocate` and sqlite `Free` and it might be hard to nail it down. If you don't plan to use allocation methods, you can just stub them or put `ATLASSERT(FALSE)` there.